# tex4ht: customized commands does not work in equation environment

Tags: tex4ht, tex4ebook

The following code does not compile under tex4ebook:

```latex
\documentclass{amsart}

\newcommand\Tag[1]{}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  x=y\label{t1}\Tag{(*)}
\end{equation}
Look at equation \ref{t1}.
\end{document}
```

It compiles of course under pdflatex. (I found an issue about a customized `\Tag`. Eventually I found that it does not even work for an empty command)

Comment: `\Tag` is internal command is used by TeX4ht to handle cross-references, so it is better to chose another name in this case. For example `\Tagged` works.

Comment: @michal.h21 Thanks. I modified it to `\newcommand\myTag[1]{\tag*{#1}}`, then there are two labels (on the left and on the right of the equation). Any workaround?

Comment: @Yai0Phah Does an equation having two labels, really!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\Tag` is internal TeX4ht command used for cross-reference handling, so it cannot be redefined without breaking of lot of things. Different name works:

```
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/520377/2891
\documentclass{amsart}

\newcommand\myTag[1]{\tag*{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  x=y\label{t1}\myTag{(*)}
\end{equation}
Look at equation \ref{t1}.
\end{document}
```

It seems that `\tag*` support has an issue that causes the label to be printed two times (once by Amsmath, then by TeX4ht). We can disable the second print using the following version of `amsmath.4ht` (I've updated the sources, so it should be available in TL soon):

```
% amsmath.4ht (2019-12-16-10:18), generated from tex4ht-4ht.tex
% Copyright 1997-2009 Eitan M. Gurari
% Copyright 2009-2019 TeX Users Group
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either
% version 1.3c of this license or (at your option) any
% later version. The latest version of this license is in
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
% and version 1.3c or later is part of all distributions
% of LaTeX version 2005/12/01 or later.
%
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status "maintained".
%
% The Current Maintainer of this work
% is the TeX4ht Project <http://tug.org/tex4ht>.
%
% If you modify this program, changing the
% version identification would be appreciated.
\immediate\write-1{version 2019-12-16-10:18}

\HRestore\cases
\HRestore\matrix
\HRestore\pmatrix
\append:def\a:display{\@displaytrue}
\expandafter\append:defIII\csname
    c:$$:\endcsname{\append:def\a:display{\@displaytrue}}



\def\above:tbinom#1#2#3#4{\a:tbinom}
\def\:temp{%
   \expandafter \ifx\csname a:tbinom\endcsname\relax \else
   \ifx\a:tbinom\empty \else
      \Configure{abovewithdelims}{\above:tbinom}{}%
   \fi\fi
   \o:tbinom:}
\HLet\tbinom\:temp
\NewConfigure{tbinom}{1}
\def\above:dbinom#1#2#3#4{\a:dbinom}
\def\:temp{%
   \expandafter \ifx\csname a:dbinom\endcsname\relax \else
   \ifx\a:dbinom\empty \else
      \Configure{abovewithdelims}{\above:dbinom}{}%
   \fi\fi
   \o:dbinom:}
\HLet\dbinom\:temp
\NewConfigure{dbinom}{1}
\def\above:binom#1#2#3#4{\a:binom}
\def\:temp#1{%
   \def\:temp{%
      \expandafter \ifx\csname a:binom\endcsname\relax \else
      \ifx\a:binom\empty \else
         \Configure{abovewithdelims}{\above:binom}{}%
      \fi\fi
      #1}}
\expandafter\:temp\expandafter{\csname o:binom :\endcsname}
\expandafter\HLet\csname binom \endcsname\:temp
\NewConfigure{binom}{1}
\pend:def\subequations{\SkipRefstepAnchor }
\def\hdots@for#1#2{\multicolumn{#2}c%
  {\m@th \hdots:for{#1}\hfil}}
\def\hdots:for#1{\dotsspace@1.5mu\mkern-#1\dotsspace@
   \xleaders\hbox{$\m@th\mkern#1\dotsspace@.\mkern#1\dotsspace@$}%
           \hfill
   \mkern-#1\dotsspace@}
\NewConfigure{hdotsfor}[1]{\def\a:hdotsfor##1{#1}}
\let\a:hdotsfor=\hdots:for
\def\:tempc{\a:hdotsfor}
\HLet\hdots:for\:tempc
\expandafter\ifx \csname tmp:muskip\endcsname\relax
   \csname newmuskip\endcsname \tmp:muskip
\fi
\expandafter\def\csname tmspace \endcsname#1#2#3{%
  \ifmmode
    \bgroup
      \tmp:muskip #1#2\edef\mathglue{\the\tmp:muskip}%
      \tmp:dim #1#3\edef\textspace{\the\tmp:dim}\a:tmspace
    \egroup
  \else \kern #1#3\fi \relax
}
\edef\:tempc{\noexpand\protect
             \expandafter\noexpand\csname tmspace \endcsname}
\HLet\tmspace=\:tempc
\NewConfigure{tmspace}{1}
\Configure{tmspace}{\mskip\mathglue}
\HRestore\over
\def\:tempc{\pic:gobble\a:over \o:@@over: \pic:gobble\b:over}
\HLet\@@over\:tempc
\HRestore\atop
\def\:tempc{\pic:gobble\a:atop \o:@@atop: \pic:gobble\b:atop}
\HLet\@@atop\:tempc
\def\::above{\pic:gobble\a:above \o:@@above:\tmp:dim
            \pic:gobble\b:above }
\def\:above{\afterassignment\::above}
\def\:tempc{\Protect\:above \tmp:dim=}
\HLet\@@above\:tempc
\HRestore\abovewithdelims
\def\::abovewithdelims#1#2{\pic:gobble\a:abovewithdelims
   \o:@@abovewithdelims:#1#2\tmp:dim\pic:gobble\b:abovewithdelims}
\def\:abovewithdelims#1#2{\def\:temp{\::abovewithdelims#1#2}%
   \afterassignment\:temp\tmp:dim}
\def\:tempc{\Protect\:abovewithdelims }
\HLet\@@abovewithdelims\:tempc
\NewConfigure{abovewithdelims}{2}
\HRestore\overwithdelims
\def\:overwithdelims#1#2{\pic:gobble\a:overwithdelims
   \o:@@overwithdelims:#1#2\pic:gobble\b:overwithdelims}
\def\:tempc{\Protect\:overwithdelims}
\HLet\@@overwithdelims\:tempc
\NewConfigure{overwithdelims}{2}
\HRestore\atopwithdelims
\def\:atopwithdelims#1#2{\pic:gobble\a:atopwithdelims
   \o:@@atopwithdelims:#1#2\pic:gobble\b:atopwithdelims}
\def\:tempc{\Protect\:atopwithdelims}
\HLet\@@atopwithdelims\:tempc
\NewConfigure{atopwithdelims}{2}
\let\ltx@label\lb:l
\let\Mathaccent:\mathaccent@
\def\mathaccent@#1#2{\ifx \EndPicture\:UnDef
     \DN@{\Picture+{}\Mathaccent:{#1}{#2}\EndPicture}%
  \else\DN@{\Mathaccent:{#1}{#2}}\fi\next@}
\def\:temp#1{{\a:boxed\leavevmode
   \vbox{\m@th$\displaystyle#1$}\b:boxed}}
\HLet\boxed\:temp
\NewConfigure{boxed}{2}
\newcommand\:temp:xrightarrow[2][]{\a:xrightarrow {\o:xrightarrow:[#1]{#2}}\b:xrightarrow}
\HLet\xrightarrow\:temp:xrightarrow
\NewConfigure{xrightarrow}{2}
\newcommand\:temp:xleftarrow[2][]{\a:xleftarrow {\o:xleftarrow:[#1]{#2}}\b:xleftarrow}
\HLet\xleftarrow\:temp:xleftarrow
\NewConfigure{xleftarrow}{2}
\def\:tempc#1{\a:eqref\o:eqref:{#1}\b:eqref}
\NewConfigure{eqref}{2}

\def\equation{\bgroup \@fleqnfalse
%
  \ifx \EndPicture\:Undef
     \def\endequation{%
       \let\tagform@=\:gobble
       \if@eqnsw \expand:after{%
          %
          \o:endequation:\b:equation\equ:no}%
       \else \expand:after{%
          \ifx\df@tag\@empty \expand:after{\o:endequation:\egroup}%
          \else
             \global\let\df:tag=\df@tag
             \expand:after{\o:endequation: \expandafter\b:equation\ifdefined\ams:delete:tag\else\df:tag\fi%
             \global\let\ams:delete:tag\@undefined
             }\fi
        }\fi
        \c:equation\egroup
      }%
      \expandafter\a:equation
   \else
      \def\endequation{\o:endequation:\egroup}%
   \fi
   \o:equation:}
\expandafter\let\csname o:equation*:\expandafter
       \endcsname \csname equation*\endcsname
\expandafter\let\csname o:endequation*:\expandafter
       \endcsname \csname endequation*\endcsname
\expandafter\def\csname equation*\endcsname{\bgroup
  \ifx \EndPicture\:Undef
     \expandafter\def\csname endequation*\endcsname {%
        \csname o:endequation*:\endcsname\egroup%
        \csname b:equation*\endcsname\egroup
      }%
      \csname a:equation*\endcsname
   \else
      \expandafter\def\csname endequation*\endcsname{\csname
                                 o:endequation*:\endcsname\egroup}%
   \fi
   \csname o:equation*:\endcsname}
\NewConfigure{equation*}[2]{
   \expandafter\c:def \csname a:equation*\endcsname {#1\bgroup \let \@eqnnum \empty }%
   \expandafter\c:def \csname b:equation*\endcsname {#2}%
}
\expandafter\def\csname genfrac \endcsname#1#2#3#4{%
  \def\@tempa{#1#2}%
  \edef\@tempb{\@nx\@genfrac\@mathstyle{#4}%
    \expandafter\noexpand\csname @@\ifx @#3@over\else above\fi
    \ifx\@tempa\@empty \else withdelims\fi\endcsname}%
  \@tempb{#1#2#3}}
\def\:tempc#1#2#3#4#5{{\a:genfrac#1\b:genfrac{\c:genfrac#4#2#3\relax
   {\d:genfrac#5\e:genfrac}}\f:genfrac}}
\HLet\@genfrac\:tempc
\NewConfigure{genfrac}{6}
\HRestore\frac
\def\:temp#1#2{{\a:frac\begingroup
   #1\endgroup\b:frac \@@over \c:frac #2\d:frac}}
\expandafter\HLet\csname frac \endcsname\:temp
\def\math@cr@@[#1]{\ifnum0=`{\fi \iffalse}\fi\math@cr@@@
   \o:noalign:{\vskip#1\relax}}
                                    \catcode`\#13 \catcode`\!6
\def\reg:align!1!2{%
   \ifx \ifinany@\:Undef\else  \inany@true\fi
  \inalign@true \ifx \displaybreak@\:UnDef
   \chardef\dspbrk@context\z@
\else
   \displaybreak@
\fi
\intertext@
   \ifingather@\else\displ@y@\fi\Let@  \let\math@cr@@@\math@cr@@@align
   \ifxxat@\else \let\tag\tag@in@align \fi
   \let\label\label@in@display !1% set st@r
   \ifst@rred\else \global\@eqnswtrue  \fi   \measure@{!2}%
   \global\row@\z@ \tabskip\eqnshift@
   \Configure{PauseMkHalign}
  {\Configure{PauseMkHalign}{}{}{}{}\expandafter\clean:span}{}{}{}%
%
   \SaveMkHalignConf:g{\align:type}\HRestore\noalign
\MkHalign#{\span
   &\@lign$\m@th\displaystyle{{\HCode{}}%
#}$%
   &\@lign$\m@th\displaystyle{{\HCode{}}%
#}$%
}!2%
}
                                    \catcode`\#=6 \catcode`\!=12
\def\clean:span#1\c:halign{%
  \TeXhalign \bgroup \:span}
\ifx \ifinany@\:Undef
   \def\:tempc{%
        \math@cr
    \EndMkHalign \RecallMkHalignConfig \csname b:\align:type\endcsname
    \ifingather@  \restorealignstate@  \egroup \nonumber
      \ifnum0=`{\fi\iffalse}\fi%
    \else         $$\fi
    \global\@ignoretrue
}

\else
   \def\:tempc{%
        \math@cr
    \EndMkHalign \RecallMkHalignConfig \csname b:\align:type\endcsname
    \ifingather@  \restorealignstate@  \egroup \nonumber
      \ifnum0=`{\fi}%
    \else         $$\fi
    \global\@ignoretrue
}

\fi
\HLet\endalign\:tempc
\def\:tempc{\pic:MkHalign{\align:type}}
\HLet\align@\:tempc
\def\Config:alg#1#2#3#4#5#6#7{%
   \expandafter\c:def\csname a:#7\endcsname{\global
      \let\sv:amps\add:amps #1}%
   \expandafter\c:def\csname b:#7\endcsname{#2\global
      \let\add:amps\sv:amps}%
   \expandafter\c:def\csname c:#7\endcsname{#3}%
   \expandafter\c:def\csname d:#7\endcsname{#4}%
   \expandafter\c:def\csname e:#7\endcsname{\expandafter\align:td
      \expandafter{\csname f:#7\endcsname}{#5}{#6}}%
}
\def\align:td#1#2#3{\iftag@
     \ifnum \add:amps>0
        \gHAdvance\add:amps  -1   \gHAdvance\HCol  -1
        \global\let#1\empty
        \ifnum \add:amps=0 \gHAdvance\HCol1 #2\gdef#1{#3}\fi
     \else #2\gdef#1{#3}\fi
   \else \gHAssign\add:amps\HCol\relax #2\gdef#1{#3}\fi}%

\def\:tempc#1{%
   \expandafter\pend:def\csname #1\endcsname{\def\align:type{#1}}%
   \NewConfigure{#1}[6]{\Config:alg{##1}{##2}{##3}{##4}{##5}{##6}{#1}}%
   \Configure{#1}{}{}{}{}{}{}%
   \def\:temp{#1}\def\:tempa{align}\ifx \:temp\:tempa\else
      \@xp\let\csname reg:#1\endcsname\reg:align
      \@xp\let\csname end#1\endcsname\endalign
   \fi }
\:tempc{alignat}
\:tempc{alignat*}
\:tempc{xalignat}
\:tempc{xalignat*}
\:tempc{xxalignat}
\:tempc{align}
\:tempc{align*}
\:tempc{flalign}
\:tempc{flalign*}
\pend:defIII\start@align{\Configure{$$}{}{}{}}
                                    \catcode`\#13 \catcode`\!6
\def\reg:start@aligned!1!2{%
   \savecolumn@
   \vcenter \bgroup
        \maxfields@!2\relax
        \ifnum\maxfields@>\m@ne
            \multiply\maxfields@\tw@
            \let\math@cr@@@\math@cr@@@alignedat
        \else
            \let\math@cr@@@\math@cr@@@aligned
        \fi
        \Let@ \chardef\dspbrk@context\@ne
        \default@tag
        \global\column@\z@
   \SaveMkHalignConf:g{start@aligned}\HRestore\noalign
\MkHalign#{&\column@plus $\m@th\displaystyle{{\HCode{}}#}$%
           &\column@plus $\m@th\displaystyle{{\HCode{}}#}$}%
}
                                    \catcode`\#=6 \catcode`\!=12
\def\al:gned#1{%
   \Configure{start@aligned}{\csname a:#1\endcsname}%
       {\csname b:#1\endcsname}{\csname c:#1\endcsname}%
       {\csname d:#1\endcsname}{\csname e:#1\endcsname}%
       {\csname f:#1\endcsname}\pic:MkHalign{#1}}
\NewConfigure{start@aligned}{6}
\def\:tempc{\crcr\EndMkHalign
    \RecallMkHalignConfig \restorecolumn@
    \egroup  \b:start@aligned}
\HLet\endaligned\:tempc
\def\:temp{%
  \let\@testopt\alignsafe@testopt
  \futurelet\:temp\aligned:a}
\def\aligned:a{\ifx [\:temp \expandafter\aligned:b
   \else \def\:temp{\aligned:b[c]}\expandafter\:temp \fi}
\def\aligned:b[#1]{%
   \al:gned{aligned}{#1}\m@ne}
\HLet\aligned\:temp
\def\reg:aligned{\reg:start@aligned}
\NewConfigure{aligned}{6}
\def\:temp{\futurelet\:temp\alignedat:a}
\def\alignedat:a{\ifx [\:temp \expandafter\alignedat:b
   \else \def\:temp{\alignedat:b[c]}\expandafter\:temp \fi}
\def\alignedat:b[#1]{%
    \let\@testopt\alignsafe@testopt
    \al:gned{alignedat}{#1}\m@ne}
\HLet\alignedat\:temp
\def\reg:alignedat{\reg:start@aligned}
\NewConfigure{alignedat}{6}
                                    \catcode`\#13 \catcode`\!6
\def\reg:gathered[!1]{%
  \RIfM@\else
      \nonmatherr@{\begin{gathered}}%
  \fi
  \null  \vcenter\bgroup
    \Let@ \chardef\dspbrk@context\@ne \restore@math@cr
    \SaveMkHalignConf:g{gathered}%
\MkHalign#{$\m@th\displaystyle{\HCode{}}#$}%
}
                                    \catcode`\#=6 \catcode`\!=12
\def\:tempc{\crcr\EndMkHalign
    \RecallMkHalignConfig \egroup\b:gathered}
\HLet\endgathered\:tempc
\def\:temp{\pic:MkHalign{gathered}}
\expandafter\HLet\csname \string\gathered\endcsname\:temp
\NewConfigure{gathered}{6}
                                    \catcode`\#13 \catcode`\!6
\def\reg:multline!1{%
  \ifx \ifinany@\:Undef\else  \inany@true\fi
    \Let@
  \@display@init{\global\advance\row@\@ne \global\dspbrk@lvl\m@ne}%
  \ifx \displaybreak@\:UnDef
   \chardef\dspbrk@context\z@
\else
   \displaybreak@
\fi
    \restore@math@cr    \let\tag\tag@in@align
  \global\tag@false \global\let\raise@tag\@empty   
  \let\tag\gobble@tag \ifst@rred  \let\label\@gobble  \else
   \stepcounter{equation}%
   \def\label{\let\cnt:currentlabel\@currentlabel
      \def\:@currentlabel{\ifx \cnt:currentlabel\@currentlabel
      \the\c@equation\else \@currentlabel\fi}%
      \anc:lbl r{equation}\ltx@label}%
   \edef\@currentlabel{\the\c@equation}%
\fi
%
  \ifst@rred
  \expandafter\let\csname e:multline*\endcsname\empty
  \expandafter\let\csname f:multline*\endcsname\empty
\fi
\SaveMkHalignConf:g{multline\ifst@rred *\fi}\HRestore\noalign
\MkHalign#{\hbox{$\m@th\displaystyle{\HCode{}}%
#$}}!1%
}
                                    \catcode`\#=6 \catcode`\!=12
\def\:tempc{\ifst@rred\else
   \e:multline\csname a:multline-num\endcsname
   \tagform@\theequation\csname b:multline-num\endcsname\f:multline
\fi
\math@cr \EndMkHalign
   \RecallMkHalignConfig \csname b:multline\ifst@rred *\fi\endcsname
   $$\global\@ignoretrue  }
\HLet\endmultline\:tempc
\def\:tempc{\pic:MkHalign{multline\ifst@rred *\fi}}
\HLet\multline@\:tempc
\NewConfigure{multline}{6}
\NewConfigure{multline-num}{2}
\@xp\let\csname reg:multline*\endcsname\reg:multline
\@xp\let\csname endmultline*\endcsname\endmultline
\NewConfigure{multline*}{4}
                                    \catcode`\#13 \catcode`\!6
\def\reg:gather!1{%
   \ingather@true  \ifx \ifinany@\:Undef
   \let\split\insplit@   \chardef\dspbrk@context\z@
\else
   \inany@true
\fi
%
   \let\tag\tag@in@align  \let\label\label@in@display
   \intertext@ \displ@y@
   \Let@  \let\math@cr@@@\math@cr@@@gather  
   \global\shifttag@false    \global\row@\@ne
  \SaveMkHalignConf:g{gather\ifst@rred *\fi}\HRestore\noalign
\MkHalign#{\hbox{$\m@th\displaystyle{{\HCode{}}%
#}$}%
&\hbox{{\HCode{}}%
#}%
}!1%
}
                                    \catcode`\#=6 \catcode`\!=12
\def\:tempc{\math@cr \EndMkHalign
   \RecallMkHalignConfig \csname b:gather\ifst@rred *\fi\endcsname
   $$\global\@ignoretrue  }
\HLet\endgather\:tempc
\def\:tempc{\pic:MkHalign{gather\ifst@rred *\fi}}
\HLet\gather@\:tempc
\NewConfigure{gather}{6}
\@xp\let\csname reg:gather*\endcsname\reg:gather
\@xp\let\csname endgather*\endcsname\endgather
\NewConfigure{gather*}{6}
\def\:tempc{%
  \def\intertext##1{%
    \ifvmode\else\\\@empty\fi
    \noalign{%
      \penalty\postdisplaypenalty\vskip\belowdisplayskip
      \vbox{\normalbaselines
        \ifdim\linewidth=\columnwidth
        \else \parshape\@ne \@totalleftmargin \linewidth
        \fi
       \a:intertext \noindent##1\b:intertext\par}%
      \penalty\predisplaypenalty\vskip\abovedisplayskip%
    }%
}}
\HLet\intertext@=\:tempc
\NewConfigure{intertext}{2}
\HLet\leftroot\:gobble
\HLet\uproot\:gobble
                                    \catcode`\#13 \catcode`\!6
\def\reg:smallmatrix{%
  \vcenter\bgroup \Let@\restore@math@cr\default@tag
  \SaveMkHalignConf:g{smallmatrix}%
\MkHalign#{$\m@th\scriptstyle#$&&%
           $\m@th\scriptstyle#$}%
}
                                    \catcode`\#=6 \catcode`\!=12
\def\:tempc{\crcr\EndMkHalign
    \RecallMkHalignConfig \egroup\b:smallmatrix}
\HLet\endsmallmatrix\:tempc
\def\:temp{\pic:MkHalign{smallmatrix}}
\HLet\smallmatrix\:temp
\NewConfigure{smallmatrix}{6}
\pend:defI\substack{\a:substack}
\append:defI\substack{\b:substack}
\NewConfigure{substack}{2}
                                    \catcode`\#13 \catcode`\!6
\def\reg:subarray!1{%
  \vcenter\bgroup
  \Let@ \restore@math@cr \default@tag
  \baselineskip\fontdimen10 \scriptfont\tw@
  \advance\baselineskip\fontdimen12 \scriptfont\tw@
  \lineskip\thr@@\fontdimen8 \scriptfont\thr@@
  \let\e:subarray\empty \let\f:subarray\empty
\everycr{}\SaveMkHalignConf:g{subarray}%
\MkHalign#{$\m@th\scriptstyle#$}%
}
                                    \catcode`\#=6 \catcode`\!=12
\def\:tempc{\crcr\EndMkHalign
    \RecallMkHalignConfig \egroup\b:subarray}
\HLet\endsubarray\:tempc
\def\:temp#1{\def\Hlcr{#1}\pic:MkHalign{subarray}{#1}}
\HLet\subarray\:temp
\NewConfigure{subarray}{4}
\NewConfigure{split}{6}
                                    \catcode`\#13 \catcode`\!6
\def\:tempc{%
   \vbox\bgroup
        \ifx \ifinany@\:Undef
   \chardef\dspbrk@context\@ne
\fi
%
        \Let@  \restore@math@cr  \default@tag \everycr{}\a:split
        \SaveMkHalignConf:g{split}\HRestore\noalign
        \MkHalign#{ $\m@th\displaystyle{{\HCode{}}%
#}$%
&$\m@th\displaystyle{{\HCode{}}%
#}$%
}}
\HLet\insplit@\:tempc
                                    \catcode`\#6 \catcode`\!12
\def\:tempc{%
   \crcr\EndMkHalign \b:split \egroup }
\HLet\endsplit\:tempc
\Configure{@begin}
  {split}
  {\relax
   \ifx  \split\insplit@ \else
   \def\choose:begin{\global\let\choose:begin\@firstoftwo
                     \@secondoftwo}%
   \fi
  }
\NewConfigure{equations}[2]{\def\pic:equa{#1}\def\pic:equb{#2}}
\def\str:pic{\ifx \EndPicture\:UnDef
      \expandafter\Picture\pic:equa{ \pic:equb}%
   \else \let\EndPicture\empty  \fi
   \let\halign\TeXhalign}
\def\make@df@tag@@#1{%
  \gdef\df@tag{\maketag@@@{#1}\def\@currentlabel{#1}\gdef\ams:delete:tag{}%
               \let\cnt:currentlabel\@currentlabel
\def\:@currentlabel{\ifx \cnt:currentlabel\@currentlabel
   \expandafter\the\csname c@equation\endcsname\else \@currentlabel\fi}%
%
               \anc:lbl r{}%
}}
\def\make@df@tag@@@#1{\gdef\df@tag{\tagform@{#1}%
  \toks@\@xp{\p@equation{#1}}\edef\@currentlabel{\the\toks@}%
  \let\cnt:currentlabel\@currentlabel
\def\:@currentlabel{\ifx \cnt:currentlabel\@currentlabel
   \expandafter\the\csname c@equation\endcsname\else \@currentlabel\fi}%
%
  \anc:lbl r{}%
  }}

\:CheckOption{new-accents}     \if:Option \else
   \HLet\Hat\hat
\HLet\Check\check
\HLet\Tilde\tilde
\HLet\Acute\acute
\HLet\Grave\grave
\HLet\Dot\dot
\HLet\Ddot\ddot
\HLet\Breve\breve
\HLet\Bar\bar
\HLet\Vec\vec

\fi
\expandafter\def\csname [ \endcsname{\st:Math}
\expandafter\def\csname ] \endcsname{\ed:Math}
\let\:tempc\measure@
\pend:defI\:tempc{\bgroup
   \RecallTeXcr \HRestore\noalign \let\EndPicture\empty
   \let\halign\TeXhalign \let\span\:span  \HRestore\begin
   \HRestore\end   \a:measure@ }
\append:defI\:tempc{\egroup}
\HLet\measure@\:tempc
\NewConfigure{measure@}{1}
\HLet\savealignstate@\empty
\renewcommand{\n:smash:}[2][tb]{%
  \def\smash@{#1}%
  \ifmmode\@xp\o:mathpalette:\@xp\mathsm@sh\else
        \@xp\makesm@sh\fi{#2}}
\let\:tempc\maketag@@@
\pend:defI\:tempc{\a:maketag}
\append:defI\:tempc{\b:maketag}
\NewConfigure{maketag}{2}
\HLet\maketag@@@\:tempc
\MathSymbol\mathrel{@cdots}
\MathSymbol\mathop{doteq}
   \def\n:doteq:{\expandafter\:same \math:sym\mathop{doteq}\nolimits}
\HLet\dotsb@=\@cdots
\HLet\intdots@=\@cdots
\HRestore\cdots
\MathSymbol\mathop{iint}
   \def\n:iint:{\expandafter\:same \math:sym\mathop{iint}\nolimits}
\MathSymbol\mathop{iiint}
   \def\n:iiint:{\expandafter\:same \math:sym\mathop{iiint}\nolimits}
\MathSymbol\mathop{iiiint}
   \def\n:iiiint:{\expandafter\:same \math:sym\mathop{iiiint}\nolimits}
\MathSymbol\mathop{idotsint}
   \def\n:idotsint:{\expandafter\:same \math:sym\mathop{idotsint}\nolimits}
\def\:tempc#1{\a:underrightarrow
   \o:underrightarrow:{#1}\b:underrightarrow}
\HLet\underrightarrow\:tempc
\NewConfigure{underrightarrow}{2}
\def\:tempc#1{\a:underleftarrow
   \o:underleftarrow:{#1}\b:underleftarrow}
\HLet\underleftarrow\:tempc
\NewConfigure{underleftarrow}{2}
\def\:tempc#1{\a:overleftrightarrow
   \o:overleftrightarrow:{#1}\b:overleftrightarrow}
\HLet\overleftrightarrow\:tempc
\NewConfigure{overleftrightarrow}{2}
\def\:tempc#1{\a:underleftrightarrow
   \o:underleftrightarrow:{#1}\b:underleftrightarrow}
\HLet\underleftrightarrow\:tempc
\NewConfigure{underleftrightarrow}{2}

\def\:tempc#1#2#3{\a:underarrow@
   \hbox{$\m@th#2#3$}\b:underarrow@
   \hbox{#1#2}\c:underarrow@
}
\HLet\underarrow@\:tempc
\def\:tempc#1#2#3{\a:overarrow@
   \hbox{#1#2}\b:overarrow@
   \hbox{$\m@th#2#3$}\c:overarrow@
}
\HLet\overarrow@\:tempc
\NewConfigure{underarrow@}{3}
\NewConfigure{overarrow@}{3}
\def\:temp#1#2{\a:overset\binrel@{#2}%
  \binrel@@{\mathop{\kern\z@#2}\limits^{#1}}\b:overset}
\HLet\overset\:temp
\NewConfigure{overset}{2}
\def\:temp#1#2{\a:underset\binrel@{#2}%
  \binrel@@{\mathop{\kern\z@#2}\limits_{#1}}\b:underset}
\HLet\underset\:temp
\NewConfigure{underset}{2}

\MathSymbol\mathop{dotsc}
\MathSymbol\mathop{dotso}
\MathSymbol\mathrel{longleftarrow}
\MathSymbol\mathrel{longrightarrow}

\ifx \ifinany@\:Undef
   \let\:tempc\gather@split
\append:defIII\:tempc{%
   \def\endmathdisplay@a{%
     \math@cr \EndMkHalign
     \RecallMkHalignConfig \csname b:gather\ifst@rred *\fi\endcsname
     \egroup 
   }%
}
\HLet\gather@split\:tempc

\else
   \:warning{ams files too old for TeX4ht}
\fi
\Hinput{amsmath}
\endinput
```

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to perform some namespace work so that TeX4ht internal commands are usually very hard to be overridden by users? It is very unfortunate that the warnings/errors on the tex side is usually useless. It does not even indicate clearly the conflicts.

Comment: @Yai0Phah it cannot be renamed unfortunately. It is even mentioned in the documentation, so it would break lot of stuff if it was changed. The name clashes in TeX are hard to debug, especially in this case, because TeX4ht uses plain TeX commands for the command definition. So it cannot report error message when it redefines  already existing command.